# Outlook Addin (AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface): First time user loads addin saves the open appointment item to calendar

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

I have written an Outlook web addin that uses a manifest which includes an **AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface** extension point. So the addin shows in the ribbon for a new meeting/appointment item created by the user in desktop Outlook 2016.

The initial page loaded in the Outlook pane for the addin simply uses a javascript function (Office.onReady) to pull the email address of the user with loadItemProps(userProfile).

It seems that when a user runs the addin for the very first time the open appointment item is automatically saved to the calendar as soon as the manifest is loaded by Outlook. This does not happen after the first time use of the addin.

There is nothing else happening on the initial page other than the Office.onReady. So it looks like Outlook is doing this when the AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface is initiated the first time.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are you seeing this in Outlook running on Windows, Mac, or Outlook on the web (OWA)?  Could you provide the version of the client as well?

Comment: It is Outlook 2016 on Windows 10. The version is 16.0.4849.1000

Comment: Could this potentially be a bug in Outlook desktop implementation of the appointmentorganizercommandsurface?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are getting email address with Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress?  And do you see the behavior if you do not call any API in Office.onReady?   What you described is surprising because with the current implementation, the emailAddress is already initialized in memory by the time Office.onReady is called.

Comment: That is correct. I am calling userProfile.emailAddress. But the issue happens even when I strip out all api calls and just leave a flat html page with no JavaScript code being called at all. In other words, I leave Office.onReady but remove the call for an email address. 

For a new first time user the appointment item gets saved. It never happens again. Just the very first load of the addin.

Comment: Launching an add-in should not cause the item to be saved (unless it calls the saveAsync API). Do you mean that it happens every first time the add-in is launched on a new appointment, or the first time after the add-in is installed (and never again)? Do you have any COM add-in installed that may be saving the item? It may be more clear if you can add a screenshot or video to show the save occurring. Thanks.